# Efficient way to insert all rows of a DataGridView into DB?

Tags: .net, datagridview

Is there any efficient way to insert all rows of a DataGridView into DB? using a foreach loop or using batch technic?

What is your option?

Thank you

Comment: What is `DataSource` of your DataGridView?

Comment: a datatable for populating it (datagridview1) but I have another datagridview (datagridview2) and 2 combobox. datagridview2 will be populated by data in datagridview1 and item which user selects from comboboxes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most efficient solutions seems to be for me:

1. Create a `DataTable`
2. Fill it in a loop (it's always a loop to fill a DataTable/DataSet)
3. [Save](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ex21zs8x.aspx) it using `SqlBulkCopy`

Comment: Thank you Mr. abatishchev. It's exactly what I was looking for

Answer (score 0):

I've done one of two things depending on the application needs.

1) You can save to the database per row, after an add/edit/delete has occured on a single row.

2) You can process them all at one time, and take the different types (add/edit/delete) using [DataSet.GetChanges](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0f8054fy.aspx) (because you should only process/save changes) and process each type differently (if needed). This is usually with a loop.

Additionally,  If you have a [TableAdapter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bz9tthwx.aspx). You can just use the Insert/Update commands as needed. They would batch process for you.

Comment: your first solution requires a loop right? If yes, Is it time-consuming?

Comment: Most solutions to this require a loop.  Even if you used Linq. There is still looping that is done.